# how to spread the image to be in the width of the web page?

Tags: css, wordpress

how to spread the image to be in the width of the web page?

you can check the website [Poklanjam](https://www.poklanjamvam.com/)

the image I want to enlarge if possible, this image of the city on the left.

what should be written as additional css

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion

The size of the image is not according to the elements created, try repeat and centre.

```
.banner-search {
    background-image: url(https://www.poklanjamvam.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/city.svg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 35%;
    background-repeat: revert;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to make the image cover the entire page.

```
.banner-search {
    
    background-image: url(https://www.poklanjamvam.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/city.svg);
    
     
    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;
            
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    }
```

Alternatively you can also position it by adding padding on the sides so it appears better on other devices

Comment: ok. I will try that also. to see if that works. tnx

Answer (score 0):

All of the above will work to center the image.

```
background-size: contain;
```

will allow the image to be its fullest view undistorted. This will look fine on mobile and smaller viewports, but will have a lot of whitespace on either side on desktop. If you're hoping for 100% width and no distorted image on desktop, you'd need to find an asset with 4x the width.